# transform.rotate(vector3.forward * Time.deltatime) is rotating the bottom of the object, not center

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I am new to unity and working on a game where a rocket flies up and down through a side-scrolling maze. Simple. The issue is the following code is rotating my rocket on the bottom rather than the center. This is similar to if you were to rotate on "pivot" mode in unity rather than on "center".

```
        private void Rotate(){

        float rotationMultiple = Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
        rigidBody.freezeRotation = true;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
             transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationMultiple);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
             transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * rotationMultiple);
        }

        rigidBody.freezeRotation = false;
    }
```

Your help means a lot as I try to get the hang of things.

Comment: `Rotate` always happens on the pivot point, that's why it is called like that.

Answer (score 3):

In order to rotate around the center of the object, use [`Renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) and [`Bounds.center`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds-center.html) to get the center point and [`Transform.RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) to rotate the transform around the center point.

You're currently using euler angles to rotate the transform, but since your euler angles vectors only have one nonzero component, we can use them as axis parameters for `RotateAround` if you keep the axis and `rotationMultiple` separate:

```
private rend;

Start() 
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

private void Rotate(){

    Vector3 centerPoint = rend.bounds.center;

    float rotationMultiple = Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
    rigidBody.freezeRotation = true;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
         transform.RotateAround(centerPoint, Vector3.forward, rotationMultiple);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
         transform.RotateAround(centerPoint, Vector3.back, rotationMultiple);
    }

    rigidBody.freezeRotation = false;
}
```

Be aware that if the shape/size of your renderer changes, the position of the center may change.

Answer (score 2):

From Unity Answers:

> When you modify the rotation of a Transform, the rotation happens around the local  origin - that is, the center of the local coordinate system for the object. The actual middle of the object may not be placed at the origin - that depends on how it was modeled.
>
> To make the rotation around the actual middle, there are a few things you could do.
>
> Rotate around the bounds center. You can use collider.bounds.center to get the center of the world space bounding box of the collider of the game object, get the center of the local space bounding box of the mesh. In both cases, you can then use RotateAround to rotate around that point. Note that for the mesh bounds, you need to transform the center into global coordinates first.
>
> Make an empty parent game object to the game object you want to rotate. Place the game object such that its middle is placed right at the origin of the parent. You can then rotate the parent game object instead using the normal ways to set the rotation of the transform.

(From https://answers.unity.com/questions/8599/how-do-i-rotate-and-object-around-its-center-in-sc.html)

This should help with your issue if I am understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This was a great learning experience for me while playing around in the Unity editor. First, the “center” vs “pivot” example I gave shows just how new I am. I figure pivot was always the bottom, turns out that’s just where it was pivoting in this case.

Ultimately the fix I was looking for was Gameobject > center on children. This set the empty rocket wrapper on the center of its children and fixed the weird rotation I was getting.

Thanks all

Comment: see and I am using Unity for quite a while now and didn't even know such a very usefull tool exists built-in :D